# What is the advantage of using home.php over index.php for the front page

Tags: theme-development, templates, homepage, frontpage

I am building a theme and wondering whether or not to include a home.php file or not. The theme (which will not be available to the public) will be mainly used with a static home page and separate blog posts page.

My understanding is that including a front-page.php file means that the static home page would be served by that file; and that if I was to include a home.php file then the blog posts would be served by that.

My question is this: If I was happy to use index.php as my blog posts layout instead of home.php then is there any advantage in having a home.php file ? Or to ask it another way: Is the only purpose of home.php that of allowing separate styling/layout of the blog posts page as compared to that of the index.php template (ie the fallback template). I should add that I have included in the theme most of the other templates ( single, archive, page etc) so I really only expect index.php to be used as a fallback and it will only operate in that regard If I've missed something so hopefully not that often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look here [[is_home vs is_front_page](http://old.nabble.com/Difference-between-is_home-and-is_front_page-td21611350.html)] you'll see that `is_front_page()` is true regardless of what the homepage is set to in the WordPress settings.  This means that if you don't plan on releasing this publicly (i.e. short-run usage) then just having a `front-page.php` should suffice.  `is_home()` is set based on your blogs page (which may or may not be the homepage, depending on whats set in WordPress Settings)

Also, here's a link to the hierarchy of which templates are chosen under what conditions: [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png)

Answer (score -2):

Actually home.php will override front-page.php for your static front page.

If you dont select blog page in Settings -> Reading , front-page.php will be displayed for blog post if exist. If it dont i will display index.php

Comment: home.php does not override front-page.php for static front page.

Comment: yes correct it doesnt - just tried it out - it does however override index.php for the posts page

Comment: Sorry for the bad info , i was sure but it seems it go it wrong